# trying to understand generators with sample code

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, generator

I'm trying to understand how generators work by converting "pipe" delimited files to csv files (3 files).

When I run below code, it is only converting and writing 1 csv file (c.csv).

I was expecting that, it will convert & write all three files(a.csv, b.csv & c.csv)

Experts, could you help me understand why its not converting 3 files?

Data in each file(3 files):

```
country|city
```

Code:

```
from typing import Iterator, Iterable

ret={
  "data": [
    {
      "src": "/Users/home/Desktop/python/a.txt"
    },
     {
      "src": "/Users/home/Desktop/python/b.txt"
    },
    {
      "src": "/Users/home/Desktop/python/c.txt"
    }]}

def extract(files:Iterable[dict])-> Iterator[dict]:
    for file in files:
        ret = file.copy()
        with open(file['src']) as f:    
            ret['data']=f.read()
    yield ret

def transform(files: Iterable[dict]) -> Iterator[dict]:
    for file in files:

        df = file_to_df(file["data"])
        ret = file.copy()
        ret['data']=df
        yield ret

def load(files: Iterable[dict]) -> Iterator[dict]:
    for file in files:
        f = open(file['src'].replace(".txt",".csv"),'w')
        f.write(file['data'])
        ret = dict(file)
        ret['dest']=file['src'].replace(".txt",".csv")
        yield ret

# Convert pipe to comma

def file_to_df (file:str, boilerplate_stripped=False):
    df = file.replace("|",",")
    return df

# Transform pipe delimited files to csv

raw_files = extract(ret['data'])   
transform_files = transform(raw_files)
load_files = load(transform_files)   

keep_keys = ['src', 'dest']
ret = {
        "data": [dict({k: v for k, v in x.items() if k in keep_keys}) for x in load_files]
    }

print (ret)
```

Result:

```
{'data': [{'src': '/Users/home/Desktop/python/c.txt', 'dest': '/Users/home/Desktop/python/c.csv'}]}
```

Expected Result:

```
{'data': [{'src': '/Users/home/Desktop/python/a.txt', 'dest': '/Users/home/Desktop/python/a.csv'},
          {'src': '/Users/home/Desktop/python/b.txt', 'dest': '/Users/home/Desktop/python/b.csv'},
          {'src': '/Users/home/Desktop/python/c.txt', 'dest': '/Users/home/Desktop/python/c.csv'}]}
```

Comment: If your code indentation is accurate, the first `yield ret` is outside the `for` loop, so `extract` is only yielding the last file.

Comment: Yes, thank you tzaman. I thought its due to generators and ended up ~ 2+ hours of reading and searching on generators flow. such a silly mistake :(. I'm not sure if I should close this question or delete it completely. Or if you post answer, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: Voting to close as typo. In the future you need to make a [mre].

Comment: @Ash You're welcome, glad I could help! For the question itself, I've already voted to close it as a typo. You could just delete it too.